# How to get the sentence / string with the matched substring

Tags: python, string, text, subquery, match

If the following content is given in a text file,

### Text1.txt

Registered : [10-01-21]       Left : [12-02-21]

Approved : [03-03-21]         Name : Ann

Ann submitted documents. Ann checked [12-04-21]

---

```
I need to get the output as :

Registered : [10-01-21]        
Left : [12-02-21]           
Approved : [03-03-21]       
checked [12-04-21]          

As the substring, we can give a regex to validate the date format.
```

```
import re
f1= open("Text1.txt")
string=f1.read()

found_p1=re.findall(r"(.*)\[[0-9]{2}[-][0-9][2][-][0-9]{2}\](.*)" ,string)
k=[ ]
for i in found_p1:
    i=re.sub(r"|',|'(|)", "", str(i))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import re

f = open("Text1.txt")
string = f.read()

pattern = re.compile("(\w+\s\[\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}\]|\w+\s[:][\s]\[\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}\])")
m = pattern.findall(string)
for i in m:
    print(i)
```